# React state in parent or child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a typeahead input using React and I'd like some input on where to place my state.
I'm only using React, and not some architecture like Redux or what have you
My root component looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import InputSearch from './input_search';
import SearchHints from './search_hints';

class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state =   
       /* Some state here? */
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <InputSearch />
      <SearchHints />
    );
  }
}
```

The `InputSearch` obviously takes care of the `<input />` markup and `SearchHints` takes care of rendering a list of suggestions as the user types

My question is whether or not I should keep my state in the root component, or place it in the different child components
The state will contain logic for matching the user input to some data array of search suggestions, and also logic for updating the value from the a selected search hint into the input field. I feel like the logic between the two child components is kind of intermingled, which I why im unsure of where to place it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always maintain your state in your root component because flow of your app revolves around your root component.So you should plan your components accordingly.

In case you feel that maintaining state of your app in root is difficult and your sub components also need to maintain some local state then you should use stores(flux,redux).

Now looking at your problem statement keeping your state at root will be a simple solution as you can just pass your state to child components and do any computations you want to do in child components.Maintaining different states for each child component will make your code more complex.

To achieve this just set your state like something

```
{input:""}
```

in your inputsearch component you can do

```
function:method(event)
{

this.props.setInput(event)


}
<input type="text" onChange={this.setInput}/>
```

In your main root component

```
function:setInputAsState(input)
{
this.setState({


input:input
])

}
<inputsearch  setInput={this.setInputAsState}/>
<SearchHints state={this.state.input}/>
```

Now compute anything you want in SearchHints component.
Hope you got an idea

Comment: Just the answer i was looking for. Thanks! So basically use events to pass the data back to the root component, and then pass it as props to the other child component?

Comment: yes as per my knowledge as i do it like that only:).Still keep looking for better ideas:)

Comment: This is actually also what i feel is the best solution, but it's always nice to get a second opinion :)

Answer (score 3):

I would keep in your root component what the user have already typed, and the last suggestion data shown. I would also pass these state members to the children.

I would go with something like this:

```
this.state = {
  text: "",
}

...

<InputSearch value={this.state.text} />

// 1st case:
<SearchHints query={this.state.text} /> 

// 2nd case:
<SearchHints hints={arrayOfSuggestions} />

// 3rd case:
<SearchHints>
  <Hint someProps />
  <Hint someProps />
  <Hint someProps />
</SearchHints>
```

In the first case, your element SearchHints looks for the suggestions.

Otherwise, you have to give it either an array of props or an array of children with the suggestions.